# Safari Prompts username/password twice when displaying audio player (html5 audio tag)

Tags: html5-audio, basic-authentication

I have a page a user logins into using basic authentication.
when the user goes to the page in their browser, they are prompted to enter in their username/password (as expected).

The problem i have is as the page loads the audio file (using the html5 audio tag), the user is prompted to login again to view the file.

Seems to only be a problem in Safari and am knocking my head on my desk trying to figure out why.  Works fine in chrome.  Anyone have experienced this in the past?

So for instance say my page is this:  http://www.example.com/playaudio.html

and on that page there is this:

```
<audio controls="controls"><source src="http://www.example.com/audio/myfile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" controls="controls">Your browser does not support the audio element.  </audio>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

well i didn't find a fix for this.  Rather, i found a workaround for it.  Although i'm not sure if i'm satisfied.  Basically i turned off authentication for mp3 files:

https://codybonney.com/serving-media-files-to-mobile-safari-behind-basic-http-authentication/